# Let $G$ be cyclic of order $n$. Let $m\in\Bbb Z,m\leq n$. Find the number of subgroups of $G$ that have order $m$. What happens if $m\nmid n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $n$. Let $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, $m \leq n$. Find the number of subgroups of $G$ that have order $m$.

My attempt:

Supose that $m\mid n$ that is, there exists $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n=km$.

$$\langle a^k\rangle=\left\{e, a^k,a^{2k},...,a^{(m-1)k}\right\} \leq G$$

Let us see that this is the only group of order $m$
$$|\langle a^s\rangle|=m \Rightarrow a^{sm}=e \Rightarrow n\mid sm$$

That is, there is an integer $t$ such that
$$sm=nt \Rightarrow a^{s}=\left(a^{n/m}\right)^t=(a^k)^t \in \langle a^k\rangle $$

Conclusion:

If $G$ is a cyclic group of order $n$, then for every $m\mid n$ there exists a unique subgroup of $G$ with order $m$.

My question:

What happens if $m$ does not divide $n$?

Comment: Division algorithm might help.

Comment: The number of subgroups of order $m$ is $1$ if $m\mid n$ and $0$ if $m\not\mid n$.

Comment: That's not a duplicate, @markvs.

Answer (score 1):

> **Lagrange's Theorem:** if $H\le G$, then the order of $H$ divides the order of $G$.

Use the contrapositive.